# Postfix not mapping UNIX users with @ character

Tags: email, postfix, virtualhost, email-server

**What I want to achieve:**

On my production server, I'm planning to have multiple users and multiple domains and my best option is to create full email-address-format unix user - when John Doe requests email account at myfirstdomain.com, he should receive username that is his exact email address - **john.doe@myfirstdomain.com**

**What do I do?**

I create (UNIX) user john.doe@myfirstdomain.com, and then map this user to email address john.doe@myfirstdomain.com, so `/etc/postfix/virtual` looks like this:

```
john.doe@myfirstdomain.com    john.doe@myfirstdomain.com
```

Then I postmap my virtual map, reload configuration and send email to address john.doe@myfirstdomain.com.

**What do I get**

immediate error saying that user **john.doe** doesn't exist - *it doesn't count full username john.doe@myfirstdomain.com*, only what's before @ - so mapping shown above doesnt work.
How to fix that?

Just to note, I am able to achieve functionality when I use UNIX user that do not have @ character.

Comment: AFAIR there are some sendmail recipes for handling OS usernames with @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're going to have to give up that dream, [rfc 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#page-26) is pretty clear about it,

`addr-spec   =  local-part "@" domain        ; global address`

Postfix will treat an `@` symbol as the terminator of the local part, and what comes afterwards as the host, I wouldn't count on being able to use local unix names with that symbol in them.

If you want your usernames to be the person's email, you can make use of the [virtual](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) table, but they won't map directly to system users.